# How to obtain the requesting user of an Azure Resource Manager Deployment?

Tags: azure, deployment, azure-resource-manager

I'm trying to see who requested a Deployment in one of my Azure subscription. I have been unable to find that information via the Azure Portal, Powershell or the Azure Resource explorer.

In Resource Explorer, I've been looking at `https://resources.azure.com/subscriptions/<subscriptionId>/resourceGroups/<resourceGroupName>/providers/Microsoft.Resources/deployments/<deploymentName>`

Via Powershell, I have been using these cmdlets:

```
Get-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName <resourceGroupName> and 
Get-AzureRmResourceGroupDeploymentOperation –DeploymentName <deploymentName> –ResourceGroupName <resourceGroupName>
```

which give a good amount of information about the deployment and all the associated operations done as part of it, but I fail to see any information regarding who requested it (username, or maybe certificate used...).

Do you know where the requesting user of a Azure RM deployment can be obtained?

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely look that up in the portal. Monitor > Activity Log. [image: I've removed sensitive data]

ps. I've removed sensitive data, but you can clearly see the user there.

Comment: Thank you. That would work for resources that were created in the last 90 days. In my case, I have resources that were created 6 month ago. Activity log only keeps 90 days worth of logs, so it doesn't appear anymore.

Comment: I guess its nowhere to be found in that case :(